# OS MasterMap layers being affected when editing other shapefiles using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, editing, os-mastermap

We use ArcGIS 10.2 to draw and edit simple grounds maintenance plans for Estates that we manage. I've done this for years, using OS MasterMap as the base. I've now got an issue that when creating or editing these layers, it's somehow also editing the underlying MasterMap layers. If I go to edit an existing polygon in one of the GM layers it's leaving a 'trace' on the MasterMap - what is appears to be doing is cutting the MasterMap as though I was using the Cut Poygon tool. Snip attached to show how it appears - I moved the coloured polygons to the current location but it's left the trace of where they were. If I go to Edit the Mastermap I can select and edit these new shapes.

[image]

Comment: 10.2 has been retired for a long time now, so you're not likely to find folks to reproduce this. This also seems to be a procedural issue -- If you edit a shapefile is *supposed* to be changed. If you don't want it changed, make it read-only to make sure it can't be changed.

Comment: Hello. Appreciate that 10.2 is old... which may be part of the problem. But I'm not editing the MasterMap, I'm editing a completely different shapefile, and in doing that it's somehow editing the MM which is in a Geodatabase

Comment: For someone to test this in ArcMap at any version I think you need to present a precise and detailed description of every step in your workflow. Be aware that most of us will not have access to Ordnance Survey data so it would be best to use a test layer that we could generate in its place.

Comment: Have you tried a new blank map, add the OSMM then your shapefile then edit only the shapefile, make sure the shapefile is in a completely different folder on a different drive?